# passthrough all columns in sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am trying to join the result of a PCA to the original features, to do this I tried a `FeatureUnion` of the PCA with a column transformer that just `passthrough` all columns

```
feature_selector = FeatureUnion(
    [
        ("original", make_column_transformer(('drop', []), reminder='passthrough'),
        ("pca", PCA())
    ])
my_pipeline = make_pipeline(preprocessor, feature_selector, model)
```

But this seems a bit counter intuitive.
Is there is any cleaner way of doing this? maybe a feature selector that select all columns instead of column transformer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think maybe the cleanest approach is to use a [`FunctionTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html).  Note in particular that the default value of the parameter `func` gives you an "identity transformer":

> [...] If func is None, then func will be the identity function.

Answer (score 2):

To Add, I found another way of doing this...

Simply using `make_pipeline('passthrough')`, the code works as expected

```
feature_selector = FeatureUnion([
     ("original", make_pipeline('passthrough')),
     ("pca", PCA())
])
my_pipeline = make_pipeline(preprocessor, feature_selector, model)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach, using just the `ColumnTransformer`.  The main ugliness here (IMO) is selecting all the columns in each transformer; there are a number of ways to specify that, but so far the cleanest seems to be a blank/default `make_column_selector`.

```py
ColumnTransformer([
    ('pass', "passthrough", make_column_selector()),
    ('pca', PCA(), make_column_selector()),
])
```